# How to Load a WebView pre-zoomed in? (In Xcode / Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am loading a UIWebview of a hosted .jpg. It's actually a schedule, so it is a rather large image. Instead of having users have to zoom in right away, I would like to load the web view already zoomed in. Although I still need the user to be able to zoom in and out, and scroll. Basically I am just looking for an "initial" zoom. How would I accomplish this? Just FYI I put the method below I am using to load the image...Thanks!

```
 // Webview code

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 5 you can access the `UIWebView`'s `scrollView` property and set the zoom level on it after the page has loaded. That would likely work as you wanted. To get the same thing on pre-iOS 5 you'd probably want to go through the `UIWebView`'s subviews until you find a `UIScrollView` and do the same thing on that.

I don't think there's any other way to programatically zoom it. Unless you can do it with Javascript and execute some using `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method.

Comment: the iOS 5 settings would work...How would I access scrollView?

Comment: You would access the `scrollView` property of your `UIWebView`... i.e. `UIWebView *webView = <some_web_view>; UIScrollView *scrollView = webView.scrollView;`

Comment: I added that line, and also declared it with `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;` What's the next line needed to specify the amount of zoom? My web view is just called "webview," so I put your line in like this:     `UIWebView *webView = webview; UIScrollView *scrollView = webView.scrollView; `
 Sorry I'm not grasping this...

Comment: If you already have the web view somewhere then just grab the scroll view from it and set the zoom scale on it. e.g. `[webview.scrollView setZoomScale:0.5f animated:NO];`. Take a look at `maximumZoomScale` and `minimumZoomScale` on the `UIScrollView` instance to see the max and min zoom scales and choose a zoom scale you want accordingly.